# Java Google App Engine bulk loader download warning “No descending index on __key__, performing serial download”

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bulkloader, objectify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App engine bulk loader download warning "No descending index on **key**, performing serial download"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217233/app-engine-bulk-loader-download-warning-no-descending-index-on-key-performi)

My post is very similar to: [App engine bulk loader download warning "No descending index on __key__, performing serial download"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217233/app-engine-bulk-loader-download-warning-no-descending-index-on-key-performi)

I essentially want to do the same thing.

Basically, I'm using the following to download all instances of one of my kinds:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --kind=ModelName --filename=ModelName.csv --application=MyAppid --url=http://MyAppid.appspot.com/remote_api
```

If the kind has more instances than the batch size, then I get this warning:

```
No descending index on __key__, performing serial download
```

This is causing my download of only around 6500 entities to take 471.4 seconds (according to the bulkloader tool once it completes). Which is really slow, as I have about 4 other kinds each even larger than this (around 15,000 entities)!

Also according to my Mac's Activity Monitor I'm only downloading at around 24Kb/second as shown by the **bandwidth** in the bulkloader output:

```
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20110514.011333
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
```

---

### My questions are:

**1) How do I get rid of this warning “No descending index on __key__, performing serial download” to get parallel downloading speeds?**

I think the answer to my the question is to add a descending index. Something like:

```
<datastore-index kind="Game" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="id" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

I tried adding this to datastore-indexes.xml file.

It deployed successfully, but I looked at my Datastore indices on the admin portal on Google, but I didn't see it serving or being built. Anyways, for the sake of it, I reran the command below, and it was still slow....

I also tried adding the same xml, but with the source="auto", to datastore-indexes-auto.xml file. However, when I tried deploying my eclipse complained with the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/datastore/index/add?app_id=<My_APP_ID>&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Creating a composite index failed: This index:
entity_type: "Game"
ancestor: false
Property {
 name: "id"
 direction: 2
}

is not necessary, since single-property indices are built in. Please remove it from your index file and upgrade to the latest version of the SDK, if you haven't already.
```

**2) Does removing this warning require me to update my auto generated bulkloader.yaml? I've included the Game kind below:**

```
python_preamble:
- import: base64
- import: re
- import: google.appengine.ext.bulkload.transform
- import: google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_wizard
- import: google.appengine.ext.db
- import: google.appengine.api.datastore
- import: google.appengine.api.users

transformers:

- kind: Game
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: id
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: __scatter__
      #external_name: __scatter__
      # Type: ShortBlob Stats: 56 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: genre
      external_name: genre
      # Type: String Stats: 6639 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: name
      external_name: name
      # Type: String Stats: 6639 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: releasedate
      external_name: releasedate
      # Type: Date/Time Stats: 6548 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: transform.import_date_time('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
      export_transform: transform.export_date_time('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

---

### Useful find

As I was typing this question. I found this [App Engine Bulk Loader Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670941/app-engine-bulk-loader-performance)

It basically explains that increasing **bandwidth_limit** to something reasonable and increasing **rps_limit** can really help speed things up.

So I tried:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --kind=ModelName --filename=ModelName.csv --application=MyAppId --url=http://MyAppId.appspot.com/remote_api --rps_limit=500 --bandwidth_limit=2500000 --batch_size=100
```

Which decreased the download time to 109.8 seconds. This is a massive reduction!

However, my target is still focused on getting rid of the “No descending index on __ key__, performing serial download” for parallel downloading.

---

### Extra information incase it might be relevant

I'm using the objectify3.0.jar to manipulate my GAE datastore. So my Game kind looks like this:

```
public class Game {
    @Id private Long id; //This is my key, auto generated by objectify  
    private String name;
    private String genre; 
    private Date releasedate;

    //ommitting getters and setters 
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't similar to that other one, it's identical. Did you try adding a descending index on `__key__`, as suggested in my answer, instead of on `id` (which isn't a reserved property, and so won't work)?

Comment: I added the following xml to datastore-indexes.xml and deployed it to google:

`<datastore-index kind="Game" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="__ key__" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>`

I'm still getting the warning.

Comment: There's a space in your property name. It's `__key__`, not `__ key__`.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the help. I think I have it working now. 

This is what I tried. I added the same xml but with source='auto' to (shown below) datastore-indexes-auto.xml in the war/WEB-INF-appengine-generated/ folder and redepolyed it to google. 

`<datastore-index kind="Game" ancestor="false" source="auto"> <property name="__key__" direction="desc"/> </datastore-index>`

I then went to the Datastore Indexes tab in my Admin Dashboard and saw __key__ built with desc.

So why does my app require this xml to appear in both datastore-indexes.xml and datastore-indexes-auto.xml for indices to build?

Comment: Btw, I also reverted my bulkloader.yaml key property from `id` to `__key__` (shown below) because my key column in my csv files were blank.

`- kind: Game
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string`

Also, how do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: The XML doesn't have to be in both files - either one would work, and you should add it to only the non-auto one. Don't worry about marking an answer - this question should be closed in favor of the other one.